# Hook On to Exit Event of Application and Show an Alert

Tags: swift, macos, nswindowcontroller

I need to show an alert box when the user quits the application by clicking on the `x` button.How can I hook on to the exit event of the application and show an alert or view controller via a segue

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
```

Please advice..

Comment: Have you looked at the delegate methods of `NSApplication`? For example, `applicationShouldTerminate:` or `applicationWillTerminate:`?

Comment: @mttrb No...Will take a look.

Comment: Did you try `applicationShouldTerminate`?

Comment: @Willeke How??????

Comment: Read the documentation of `applicationShouldTerminate`, search SO for "applicationShouldTerminate", Google "applicationShouldTerminate alert". Try to use `applicationShouldTerminate`. Add the new issues to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to use a segue to do this because they're just so convenient, but segues can't be done in a storyboard going from app delegate events like "`applicationWillResignActive`" (going to background) or "`applicationWillBecomeActive`" (becoming foreground again).

The correct way to do this would be via an alert.  And you'd likely want to do this in `applicationShouldTerminate`, since you probably want to A) be able to abort quitting if you have a good reason not to quit just yet or B) give the user a choice whether or not to really quit.

Here's how it would look in swift 4:

```
var licenseWindowController : LicenseWindowController?

func dialogOKCancel(question: String, text: String) -> Bool {
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = question
    alert.informativeText = text
    alert.alertStyle = .warning
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
    return alert.runModal() == .alertFirstButtonReturn
}

func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {

    let answer = dialogOKCancel(question: "Ok?", text: "Should we really quit?")
    if answer == true
    {
        return .terminateNow
    } else {

func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {

    let answer = dialogOKCancel(question: "Ok?", text: "Should we really quit?")
    if answer == true
    {

        return .terminateNow

    } else {

        // to bring up a window from your storyboard...
        let mainStoryboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
        self.licenseWindowController = mainStoryboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "LicenseWindowController")) as? LicenseWindowController
        if let actualLicenseWC = self.licenseWindowController
        {
            actualLicenseWC.showWindow(self)
        }

        return .terminateCancel
    }
}
```

***Swift 3***

```
var licenseWindowController : LicenseWindowController?

func dialogOKCancel(question: String, text: String) -> Bool {
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = question
    alert.informativeText = text
    alert.alertStyle = .warning
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
    return alert.runModal() == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn
}

func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplicationTerminateReply {

    let answer = dialogOKCancel(question: "Ok?", text: "Should we really quit?")
    if answer == true
    {
        return .terminateNow
    } else {
        let mainStoryboard = NSStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        self.licenseWindowController = mainStoryboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "LicenseWindowController") as? LicenseWindowController
        if let actualLicenseWC = self.licenseWindowController
        {
            actualLicenseWC.showWindow(self)
        }

        return .terminateCancel
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But the use case is to give a message to the user in case he/she is using the trial version of the software.Like"You are using the trial,Do you have a Key?" --> "Yes";Then launch a new view controller using a segue of sheet type..that allow the user to enter the license data... I need a way to show the segue if the user decides not to quit the application or presses a button in the alert..Is this possible? Please advice..

Comment: I've edited the code to bring up a License Key Window Controller if the "cancel" button is hit in the quit alert.  Make sure you set the correct identifier on the window controller in your storyboard.  You can also get the window and display it as a sheet, if you know what the parent window is.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. But I'm getting the following errors.Please see https://imgur.com/a/CxtZ2 Im running Xcode 8

Comment: I've edited my question again.  Would have been nice if you had mentioned you were using Xcode 8 to begin with, instead of the current shipping Xcode 9.

Comment: Thanks.Sorrry about it.I will check and get back to you .Also does using Xcode 8 Restrict compatibilty in any way?

Comment: You will eventually need to upgrade to Xcode 9 (sooner, because Apple will stop accepting app submissions from Xcode 8 any day now) and Swift 4 (a little later on, provided you check the right flags for Swift compability).

Comment: Thanks .. The confirmation message does not appear unless I add   `override func viewDidAppear()        {
        self.view.window?.delegate = self
    }
   
    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: Any) {  NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)}`  to the ViewController of the Main Window.If I remove this code... nothing happens.

Comment: sorry I did not notice your latest comment.Please see my last comment.Its not working.

Comment: did you try adding the above code (in my answer) to AppDelegate.swift ?

Comment: yeah... it does not show an alert dialog unless i set the Delegate in the ViewController.swift file and explicitly call terminate.But even then, this does not prevent the application from quitting.

Answer (score 0):

In your appdelegate you should be able to put your code into `applicationWillTerminate` and make the message appear there.

Edit: You would probably be better off using a modal alert instead of a segue.